# How can i run a stage only if a Pull Request has been raised in YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Im learning YAML and want a stage to run only when a PULL Request has been made on a particular branch. How can i do this?

Answer (score 5):

To run a stage only when a pull request has been made on a particular branch, you can set the condition in the stage.

```
condition: and(eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/branchname'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

Here is an example:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  condition: and(eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/branchname'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: xx
```

You can use predefined variables: `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` and `Build.Reason` to filter the trigger method and pull request target branch.

For more detailed info, you can refer to the docs: [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).